# I cant get the correct values of list in function returns python

Tags: python

I have a function get_board to fill a 2d list with increasing numbers.

```
size= int (input("Size"))

def get_board(size):
   i=0
   num=0
   board = [[0] * size] * size
   for i in range(size):
      j=0
      for j in range(size):
        board[i][j]=num
        num+=1
   return board

board= get_board(size)

print (board[0][0])
```

I cant get the correct values. If the size is 3, board starts with 6 7 8. The example board[0][0] is equal to 6.
I didnt get that.

Comment: You can't create list elements by assigning to indexes. You have to use `board.append()`.

Comment: That code throws a NameError. Can we see your *real* code?

Comment: Is there some other code that initializes the `board` variable?

Comment: I'm guessing you have code like `board = [[0] * size] * size` That makes all the rows references to the same list.

Comment: Thanks sir @Barmar

Comment: Your last few sentences aren't very clear: Do you mean that you expect the values to be `6, 7, 8`, or do you mean that those are the values you got?

Comment: I wanted increasing numbers, but got these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use numpy for this: `numpy.arange(size ** 2).reshape(size, size)`.

Comment: Very useful. Thank you